# C++: generate template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I run into the unfortunate situation that I need to write the following code:

```
std::map<type1_key, type1_value, type1_cmp> x;
std::map<type2_key, type2_value, type2_cmp> y;
std::map<type3_key, type3_value, type3_cmp> z;
// ...
```

These key/value/cmp types are predefined for me.  Their type names all follow this _key, _value, and _cmp pattern (those are not templates).  Is there a built-in way to simplify this into

```
map_type<type1> x;
// ...
```

or

```
map_type(type1) x; // some kind of macro??
// ...
```

Comment: Its up to you, but that sounds an awful idea. Try not to obscure code with macros like that unless your intent is to make it hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the macro solution preferable, but here is a version that wraps the information in a traits structure, if you don’t want the macro to pollute the global scope:

```
#define make_traits(T) \
struct T##_traits { \
  typedef T##_key key; \
  typedef T##_value value; \
  typedef T##_cmp cmp; \
}

make_traits(type1);
make_traits(type2);
make_traits(type3);

#undef make_traits

template<typename T>
using map_type =
  std::map<typename T::key, typename T::value, typename T::cmp>;

map_type<type1_traits> x;
```

Comment: Just curious: Why do you find the macro solution preferable over this one?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: It takes less code, and the purpose of the macro (reducing syntactic duplication) is obvious. I would use this solution if I planned to reuse the trait types for more than just `map_type`, though.

Comment: One problem I found is if I define a function template: `template <typename traits> f(const map_type<traits>& a)`, it seems `f(x)` cannot find a match?  I have to explicitly write `f<type1_traits>(x)`.

Comment: @MetroWind all three usages of `T` inside `map_type<T>` are non-deducible, so indeed `T` itself cannot be deduced. But you can do `template <class K, class V, class C> void f(std::map<K, V, C> &);`.

Comment: @Quentin I see...  Is there a place (in the standard?) that documents what kinds of cases are deducible and non-deducible?

Comment: @MetroWind certainly. I don't have quotations at hand, but [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) usually provides a nice transcript. It is, however, fairly hairy wording, so intuition works great in simple cases -- just ask yourself whether the compiler has enough information to do the deduction. [cont.]

Comment: @MetroWind In this case for example, given `struct Foo { using type = int; };` and `struct Bar { using type = int; };`, calling `template <class T> void f(T::type)` as `f(0)` leaves no way of knowing whether `T` should be `Foo` or `Bar` to provide the required `int` typedef. Thus, nested types are non-deducible.

Comment: @Quentin That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use following macro:

```
   #define map_type( x ) std::map<x##_key, x##_value, x##_cmp>
```

Then,

```
map_type(type1) x;
```

Comment: Ha!  Didn't know macro can do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an approach that uses the type system more

```
template <std::size_t I>
struct kvc;

template <>
struct kvc<1> {
    using key = type1_key;
    using value = type1_value;
    using cmp = type1_cmp;
};
// Similar for the other types

template <std::size_t I>
using map_type = 
    std::map<typename kvc<I>::key, typename kvc<I>::value, typename kvc<I>::cmp>;
```

You can automate the creation of the specializations with a macro, but this way you have more fine tuned control of the key/value/cmp and you get (in my opinion) nicer errors.